# How to get UEFI firmware settings back?

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, uefi, boot-loader

I had a Windows and Ubuntu boot USB and running fine
until I installed a Kali Linux USB bootable.

Now I can only use Ubuntu and Kali. I cannot access Windows OS boot manager nor UEFI firmware after using "recommended fixes" from boot repair.

How can I get back the option to go back to Windows and UEFI firmware settings back on my HP laptop?

Here is my boot load order:

```
efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0007
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0007,0004,000A,000C,000D,000B,0000
Boot0000  Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,92061524-8658-46f6-8c70-bdf8accf8897,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,2288cc9d-9424-4bb5-8f6e-38f75cd6b7df,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0007* kali  HD(1,GPT,2288cc9d-9424-4bb5-8f6e-38f75cd6b7df,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\kali\grubx64.efi)
Boot000A* Internal Hard Disk    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,8C-E3-8E-04-02-D9-09-AA)/HD(1,GPT,2288cc9d-9424-4bb5-8f6e-38f75cd6b7df,0x800,0x100000)..BO
Boot000B* USB Drive (UEFI) - General USB Flash Disk 1100    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x8,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x3)/USB(1,0)/USB(0,0)/CDROM(1,0x8a578,0x7d00)..BO
Boot000C* USB Drive (UEFI) - General USB Flash Disk 1100    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x8,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x3)/USB(1,0)/USB(0,0)/HD(2,MBR,0x105b854a,0x8a578,0x1f40)..BO
Boot000D* USB Drive (UEFI) -  USB DISK 2.0 PMAP PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x8,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x3)/USB(1,0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x43a1d947,0x800,0x39b3800)..BO
```

Comment: btw, it does windows os boot manager does not show on grub customizer

Comment: If you ran Boot-Repair post in question above the link it gives to the Summary Report, so we can see details. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Grub Customizer replaces all the grub scripts with its own proxy files. Best to uninstall Grub Customizer & totally reinstall grub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your system is running linux, you're most likely chainloading GRUB from your computer's UEFI firmware. If this is so, use the following steps to add Windows to your GRUB menu:

1. Press `SHIFT` while booting into Ubuntu.
2. The GRUB boot menu should appear. Press `c` to enter
   the GRUB command line.
3. Type `ls`. You should get a result similar to this (if your installation is old, you might see `msdos` instead of `gpt`) :

```
(hd0) (hd0, gpt1) (hd0, gpt2) (hd1) (hd1, gpt1) (hd1, gpt2) (hd1, gpt3)
```

4. Type `ls (hd0, gpt1)/` replacing `(hd0, gpt1)` with each drive you find listed until you find the drive containing Windows.
5. Write down the drive that contains Windows. Then reboot Ubuntu. Add the following to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, replacing `(hd0, gpt1)` with whatever drive that contains Windows:

```
menuentry "Windows" {
  insmod fat
  insmod chain
  set root=(hd0, gpt1)
  chainloader (hd0, gpt1)/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

6. Place a `#` in front of  `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` to show the GRUB boot menu on boot.
7. Run `sudo update-grub`
8. Reboot. The GRUB menu should now show and Windows should now be an option.